# How to check and change an image in ImageButton

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton[] ib;
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ib = new ImageButton[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < ib.length; i++) {
            {
                String buttonID = "imageButton" + (i + 1);
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
                ib[i] = ((ImageButton) findViewById(resID));
                ib[i].setOnClickListener(this);

            }
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        for (int i = 0; i < ib.length; i++) {
            if (ib[i].getId() == v.getId()) {
                ib[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.img_b);
            }
            if (ib[2].getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_b).getConstantState()) {
                ib[1].setImageResource(R.drawable.img_c);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

There are 10 ImageButtons with 'img_a.' If I click one of ImageButtons, img_a changes to img_b.

Now I want to add that if I click ib[2] or imagebutton2, ib[1] changes to img_c. 
I used getDrawable().getConstantState(). It has no error, but it is not working.
Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to apply the change when clicking on imagebutton2 do this

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    for (int i = 0; i < ib.length; i++) {
        if (ib[i].getId() == v.getId()) {
            ib[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.img_b);
        }
    }
    if (v.getId() = R.id.imageButton2) {
        ib[1].setImageResource(R.drawable.img_c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I want to change ib[1], if both ib[2] and ib[3] are img_b? Using just '&&' doesn't work..

Comment: @Kew you would need to check the buttons state because the onClick event will be called once for each button.